# pick month start and end data in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have stock data downloaded from yahoo finance. I want to pickup data in the row corresponding to monthly start and month end. I am trying to do it with python pandas data frame. But I am not getting correct method to get the starting & ending of the month. will be great full if somebody can help me in solving this. 
Please note that if 1st of the month is holiday and there is no data for that, I need to pick up 2nd day's data. Same rule applies to last of the month also. Thanks in advance.

Example data is

```
2016-01-05,222.80,222.80,217.00,217.75,15074800,217.75
2016-01-04,226.95,226.95,220.05,220.70,14092000,220.70
2015-12-31,225.95,226.55,224.00,224.45,11558300,224.45
2015-12-30,229.00,229.70,224.85,225.80,11702800,225.80
2015-12-29,228.85,229.95,227.50,228.20,7263200,228.20
2015-12-28,229.05,229.95,228.00,228.90,8756800,228.90
........
........
2015-12-04,240.00,242.15,238.05,241.10,11115100,241.10
2015-12-03,244.15,244.50,240.40,241.10,7155600,241.10
2015-12-02,250.55,250.65,243.75,244.60,10881700,244.60
2015-11-30,249.65,253.00,245.00,250.20,12865400,250.20
2015-11-27,243.00,250.50,242.80,249.70,15149900,249.70
2015-11-26,241.95,244.90,241.00,242.50,13629800,242.50
```

Comment: When asking question you should provide what code you've already written.

Answer (score 0):

For the first / last day of each month, you can use `.resample()` with `'BMS'` and `'BM'` for `Business Month (Start)` like so (using `pandas 0.18` syntax):

```
df.resample('BMS').first()
df.resample('BM').last()
```

This assumes that your data have a `DateTimeIndex` as usual when downloaded from `yahoo` using `pandas_datareader`:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pandas_datareader.data import DataReader
df = DataReader('FB', 'yahoo', datetime(2015, 1, 1), datetime(2015, 3, 31))['Open']

df.head()

Date
2015-01-02    78.580002
2015-01-05    77.980003
2015-01-06    77.230003
2015-01-07    76.760002
2015-01-08    76.739998
Name: Open, dtype: float64
df.tail()

Date
2015-03-25    85.500000
2015-03-26    82.720001
2015-03-27    83.379997
2015-03-30    83.809998
2015-03-31    82.900002
Name: Open, dtype: float64
```

do:

```
df.resample('BMS').first()

Date
2015-01-01    78.580002
2015-02-02    76.110001
2015-03-02    79.000000
Freq: BMS, Name: Open, dtype: float64
```

and

```
df.resample('BM').last()
```

to get:

```
Date
2015-01-30    78.000000
2015-02-27    80.680000
2015-03-31    82.900002
Freq: BM, Name: Open, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should convert your date column to datetime format, then group by month, then sort groupby Series by date and take the first/last from it using head/tail methods,  like so:

```
In [37]: df
Out[37]:
           0       1       2       3       4         5       6
0 2016-01-05  222.80  222.80  217.00  217.75  15074800  217.75
1 2016-01-04  226.95  226.95  220.05  220.70  14092000  220.70
2 2015-12-31  225.95  226.55  224.00  224.45  11558300  224.45
3 2015-12-30  229.00  229.70  224.85  225.80  11702800  225.80
4 2015-12-29  228.85  229.95  227.50  228.20   7263200  228.20
5 2015-12-28  229.05  229.95  228.00  228.90   8756800  228.90
In [25]: import datetime

In [29]: df[0] = df[0].apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d')
)
In [36]: df.groupby(df[0].apply(lambda x: x.month)).apply(lambda x: x.sort_value
s(0).head(1))
Out[36]:
              0       1       2       3      4         5      6
0
1  1 2016-01-04  226.95  226.95  220.05  220.7  14092000  220.7
12 5 2015-12-28  229.05  229.95  228.00  228.9   8756800  228.9

In [38]: df.groupby(df[0].apply(lambda x: x.month)).apply(lambda x: x.sort_value
s(0).tail(1))
Out[38]:
              0       1       2      3       4         5       6
0
1  0 2016-01-05  222.80  222.80  217.0  217.75  15074800  217.75
12 2 2015-12-31  225.95  226.55  224.0  224.45  11558300  224.45
```

You can merge the result dataframes, using pd.concat()

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have downloaded data from Yahoo:

```
> import pandas.io.data as web 

> import datetime

> start = datetime.datetime(2016,1,1) 

> end = datetime.datetime(2016,5,1)

> df = web.DataReader("AAPL", "yahoo", start, end)
```

You simply pick the month end and start rows with:

```
df[df.index.is_month_end] 

df[df.index.is_month_start]
```

If you want to access a specific row, like the first row of the first starting day of the selected starting days, you simply do:

```
df[df.index.is_month_start].ix[0]
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the help. I am able to solve it. I realized my pandas version is very old. After upgrading it i am able to use the examples given by our friends above. thanks